# Ruby if Model.exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Have SubscriberList

When an order is placed I want to check if New User's email is all ready in our subscribers list.

If not, then add them.  Problem is it adds them no matter what.  Guess it's not performing check correctly.

Currently in my orders_controller I have

```
unless logged_in?
  @order.subscribe_after_purchase(@order.user.email)
end
```

And in my Order.rb  I have

```
def subscribe_after_purchase(email)
   unless SubscriberList.exists?(email)
     SubscriberList.create(:email => email)
   end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
unless SubscriberList.exists?(:email => email)
  SubscriberList.create(:email => email)
end
```

When you just pass the email address to the `exists?` method then ActiveRecord will interpret it as a primary key. Alternatively, you can use:

```
SubscriberList.find_or_create_by_email(email)
```

—which will have the same effect as your `unless` block; creating the record unless it already exists.

- [`exists?` API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001782)

Comment: find_or_create_by_email works, forgot about that which this works too.  You where right, needed to add the :email => email.  But for some reason the "unless" block didn't work in my model.  I changed it to "if" and put the code in the "else" section and it started to work.